# Searching for a specific key-value in GoLang buffer variable

Tags: arrays, json, go

I have a variable buffer that stores a set of key-value pairs in the array of the form:

**[{"Key":"area1", "Record": {"name":"belfast","type":"surburban","validity":"true"}},{Key,Record},{Key,Record}....]** i.e a set of Key-Record pairs in a buffer array.

Now I want to retrieve only the key-record pairs that have a specific record entry, for example i want only records that have the value "true" in validity, I want to return all key-record pairs that have the validity field value as true. Any suggestions ? Thanks

Here is a code segment of how the key-record pairs are created after which I want to filter key-records that have validity as true

```
var buffer bytes.Buffer
    buffer.WriteString("[")

    bArrayMemberAlreadyWritten := false
    for resultsIterator.HasNext() {
        queryResponse, err := resultsIterator.Next()
        if err != nil {
            return shim.Error(err.Error())
        }
        // Add a comma before array members, suppress it for the first array member
        if bArrayMemberAlreadyWritten == true {
            buffer.WriteString(",")
        }
        buffer.WriteString("{\"Key\":")
        buffer.WriteString("\"")
        buffer.WriteString(queryResponse.Key)
        buffer.WriteString("\"")

        buffer.WriteString(", \"Record\":")
        // Record is a JSON object, so we write as-is
        buffer.WriteString(string(queryResponse.Value))
        buffer.WriteString("}")
        bArrayMemberAlreadyWritten = true
    }
    buffer.WriteString("]")
```

So the buffer array has the key-record pairs and I want to filter it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can `unmarshal` the data into a struct, you can use the following code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type DataStructure struct {
    Key    string `json:"Key"`
    Record struct {
        Name     string `json:"name"`
        Type     string `json:"type"`
        Validity bool   `json:"validity"`
    } `json:"Record"`
}

var data string = `[{"Key":"area1", "Record": {"name":"belfast","type":"surburban","validity":true}},{"Key":"area1", "Record": {"name":"belfast","type":"surburban","validity":false}}]`

func main() {
    var datastruct []DataStructure

    var result []DataStructure
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &datastruct); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, item := range datastruct {
        if item.Record.Validity {
            result = append(result, item)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Input:

```json
[{"Key":"area1", "Record": {"name":"belfast","type":"surburban","validity":true}},{"Key":"area1", "Record": {"name":"belfast","type":"surburban","validity":false}}]
```

Expected result:

```
[{Key:area1 Record:{Name:belfast Type:surburban Validity:true}}]
```

Comment: this is nice ! what if I want it in the same format as the "var data string" , that is returned as [{Key:area1 Record:{Name:belfast Type:surburban Validity:true}}], because I think the above code would return the result as [{area1 {belfast surburban true}}] right ?

Comment: Use `fmt.Println(result)` instead of `fmt.Printf("%+v",result)`